# How to integrate Appsync api in android

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have given an amazon api to integrate. But I have no idea how to use this api

```
 mutation createTrail {
   createTruckTrailer(input:{truckId: "077",trailer:["AB22D"]}){
    result
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet you've been given is an example of a GraphQL query, which can be sent to a GraphQL-enabled endpoint, such as the one you've been given which is hosted using AWS AppSync. A GraphQL query is structured differently than a REST api call; think of it as a structured way of making REST calls. Requests are sent to the ApiUrl you pasted above in a POST HTTP request, with a request body that looks like:

```
{
    "query": "mutation createTrail {\n createTruckTrailer(input:{truckId: \"077\",trailer:[\"AB22D\"]}){\n result }\n }",
    "operationName": "createTrail",
    "variables": {}
}
```

However additional headers are necessary to authenticate with IAM. The response from the server will include the result as JSON. I highly recommend spending just a few minutes to become a little more familiar with GraphQL here: https://graphql.org/learn/

To make calls to this AppSync endpont from Android, take a look at the Amplify android client, which explains how to get started here (Skip step 4): https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start, and then setup your client to authenticate with IAM to your backend here: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/api#iam

Once your amplify client is fully set up, you can make the GraphQL Mutation shown above by following the steps here: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/api#import-sdk-and-config

Answer (score 0):

Use retrofit with rxJava or coroutines.

Comment: But this looks like not even json structure.

Comment: For android app to hit rest API , it needs endpoint and base url. Do you have required inputs?

Comment: boral-iot-bt-appsync-dev-api_AWS_IAM": {
            "ApiUrl": "https://z7sirzvphfgobgf4xvj6il72s4.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
            "Region": "ap-southeast-2",
            "AuthMode": "AWS_IAM",
            "ClientDatabasePrefix": "boral-iot-bt-appsync-dev-api_AWS_IAM"
        } @Ashok kumar This is what they given

Comment: I tried this url in browser but getting unauthorised error as Jason https://z7sirzvphfgobgf4xvj6il72s4.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/graphql?Region=ap-southeast-2&AuthMode=AWS_IAM&ClientDatabasePrefix=boral-iot-bt-appsync-dev-api_AWS_IAM

Comment: You may need some API key aswell to access the url. First try to get the proper response through browser or postman tool. Once this achieved we will have proper inputs and we can proceed to integrate in app

Comment: But they said, this will not work in postman because this is aws api.

Comment: Also json structure looks like array and objects. But this looks like not even json structure.

Comment: Then how you can test whether service is sending  correct response and is working fine. Are they use any other tool?